# Force.com Site - Custom Forgot Password page not working, throwing unauthorized page error

Tags: force.com-sites, passwords

We have a Force.com site where we enabled login options and for the forgot Password link on the login page settings we have added a custom Forgot Password page.

When I try to navigate to this Forgot Password page(using sites), the page doesn't open and instead it redirects me to an Unauthorized page stating: "Authorization Required ('You must first log in or register before accessing this page)"

- We have checked site profile settings, security settings and profile
  access for custom Forgot Password page and everything seems ok.
- Debug logs are not showing anything useful.
- Cache attribute too is set to false

Any clue or directions here?

Comment: Sites will "Authorization Required" rather than disclosing error messages which could yield details of your code. Go to `Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs` and create one for the `Site Guest User` - this might give you some more insight into what is failing.

Comment: Is the custom page added to the guest user profile of the site ?

Comment: Generally the debug logs for force.com sites are rubbish, whenever I have had this (and all profile and config settings are correct) it has been due to the controller / class throwing an exception that is not handled. Have you tried accessing the page from within SFDC i.e. apex/PageName in your browser and check the logs to ensure no expections are being thrown

Comment: @user320 : Thank you! As mentioned in my main post, I already tried that and the Debug logs are not showing anything useful.

Comment: @Sdry : Thank you! yes the page is already added/enabled for guest user profile.

Comment: @MahatHussein : Thank you! yes I tried to access page internally ie /apex/PageName and its working great there.

Comment: Sanity check: do you have an actual Portal enabled under `Login Settings`?

Comment: @user320 : yes, enabled for a customer portal. Thanks for sanity check, sometimes a different eye really helps. But as of now still clueless about this error.

Comment: @ChiragMehta Do you have any custom URL redirects happening ?

Comment: To my best knowledge, I was able to debug this using 3rd approach mentioned @ http://www.tgerm.com/2010/10/debugging-sites-authorization-required.html

Answer (score 2):

This is nearly always down to an exception being thrown, and that can be down to things like field level security.

It seems odd that there's nothing in the logs, you should definitely see an exception there but the things to check are:

- Permissions for objects used in the controller/page
- Field Level Security for objects used in the controller/page (so easy to get a null value here and hence a null dereference). FLS for sites is accessed via the site guest profile and isn't listed in the main profile list
- Check that there's not a redirect happening to a page the guest profile DOESN'T have access to

Comment: Thank you!
The page is almost clone of standard forgot password page. So no issue of FLS or etc. Post reset password submit there's redirection to password confirm page, but that too is enabled for guest profile.

Comment: If it's basically a copy of that then I'd suggest doing a diff between the two as it'll be one of the differences that's breaking things!

Comment: Ok will do. PS: 1 in 100 times the page worked. And I tried Abhinav's 3rd approach (listed at http://www.tgerm.com/2010/10/debugging-sites-authorization-required.html) and it resulted in error "System.VisualforceException : Page not allowed for the profile" - but I'm sure its enabled for guest profile and customer portal profile too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to any resource like an image which requires salesforce authentication in your forget password page?

Comment: nope. I tried an empty page with just apex:page line and it still says authorization required.